# Using an Array being passed by a function.

Tags: c++, arrays

```
// This program demonstrates an array being passed to a function 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void showValues(int [], int) ; //Function prototype.

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 8;
    int number [ARRAY_SIZE] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40};

    showValues (number, ARRAY_SIZE);
    return 0;
}   
    //Definition of function showValue.
    //This function accpets an array to integers and 
    //the array's size as its arguments. The contents. 
    //of the array are displayed. 

    void showValues (int nums[], int size)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            cout << nums [index] << " ";
            cout << endl;

    }
```

Using C++, Studying arrays, the program works fine, however; I am not understanding the for loop on the bottom where it says "index < size"
Where is "size" getting its value from that the for loop knows when to stop looping?

Comment: It is recommended to use all uppercase symbols for preprocessor to avoid name collision. Previously constants were defined by preprocessor so they were uppercase. When you do not use #define to define a constant, why you still use uppercase and increase probablity of the problem rather than solving it? Why to follow habit blindly?

Comment: This is one of the examples I used from a book I am reading. I copied the coding exactly as is. I'll keep that tip in mind as I progress. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`size` is passed as a *parameter* to the function `showValues`.

That function is called from `main()`, passing `ARRAY_SIZE` as that parameter.

`ARRAY_SIZE` is defined as the size of the array.

Actually, you could write

`int number [] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40};`

since the compiler can figure out the array size from the initialisation array. The function call can be refactored to

`showValues(number, sizeof(number) / sizeof(int));`

`sizeof(number) / sizeof(int)` is an idiomatic way of evaluating the number of elements in an array. Some folk prefer `sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0])` since then the code is not sensitive to the *type* of the array. You can then remove `ARRAY_SIZE` entirely.

Comment: Wow, awesome.  I get it now, had to read it a few times but well explained. THANK YOU very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `showValues (number, ARRAY_SIZE);` call

passes the array as well as its size to `void showValues (int nums[], int size)`

Therefore size in the for loop gets the value 8

Answer (score 0):

```
 void showValues (int nums[], int size)
```

The second parameter to the function showValues becomes the size in your for loop.

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 8;

showValues (number, ARRAY_SIZE);
```